# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface retrofit2.http.Url. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type to fix this problem

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gson

I have a problem with `Retrofit` and `Gson` and I don't know why?

My app has an error when I send data for login:

> Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface retrofit2.http.Url.
>   Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type to fix this
>   problem.

Earlier, I made this app with Java and had exactly the same code and didn't have any error. But why now with Kotlin??

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val editText_login_user=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Login_username)
            val editText_login_password=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Login_password)
            val button_login=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_login)
            button_login.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { Connect_login(editText_login_user.text.toString(),editText_login_password.text.toString()) })
    }
    fun Connect_login(user:String,pass:String):Boolean{
        var client= OkHttpClient()
        var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://sobosha.ir/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val services=retrofit.create(ApiRet::class.java)
        val call =services.Logindata(user,pass)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<User_info>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<User_info>, response: retrofit2.Response<User_info>) {
                val user: User_info? = response.body()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, user?.name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<User_info>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val editText_login_passwords=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Login_password)
                editText_login_passwords.setText(t.message)
            }
        })
        return false
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ApiRet {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/Login.php")
    Call<User_info> Logindata(@Field("username") String user, @Field("password") String pass);
}
```

and my User_info:

```
class User_info{

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("image_url")
    var image_url: Url? = null
    @SerializedName("correct")
    var correct:Boolean ?= null
}
```

And i change interface to this

```
interface Apiservices{

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Login.php")
    fun Login(@Field("username") user: String, @Field("password") pass: String): Call<User_info>
}
```

But it doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use `retrofit2.http.Url`. It's just an annotation class. You can change it to `HttpUrl` for example:

```
class User_info{

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("image_url")
    var image_url: HttpUrl? = null
    @SerializedName("correct")
    var correct:Boolean ?= null
}
```

Then you have to create and register custom url deserializer:

```
class UrlDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<HttpUrl> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): HttpUrl =
        HttpUrl.get(json.asString)

}
```

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(HttpUrl::class.java, UrlDeserializer())
    .create()
var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://sobosha.ir/")
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

Comment: It's true:)
TNX